# Getting the most recent date from a reference table

Tags: sql, join, apache-spark-sql, query-optimization

Could someone explain the significance of the subquery present in the where not exists. Also, which would be a better option,either to go with the below option or by joining the maxdate to the base table.

```
SELECT i.the_date, p.the_date AS pricing_date, i.good, i.quantity, p.price
FROM   inventory  i
LEFT   JOIN price p ON p.good = i.good AND p.the_date <= i.the_date
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM price p1
   WHERE  p1.good = p.good
   AND p1.the_date <= i.the_date
   AND p1.the_date >  p.the_date
   );
```

Comment: I'd consider the join alternative.

Comment: Join alternative will be better for performance. SQL statements that use the EXISTS condition are very inefficient since the sub-query is rerun for EVERY row in the outer query's table

Comment: @GauravS . . . That is simply not true.  `NOT EXISTS`/`EXISTS` can be the fastest way to execute queries, particularly if the tables have the correct indexes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff:- Thanks for the inputs. When you are saying not true, Are you referring that subs query with NOT EXISTS/EXISTS will not run for each statement of outer query OR you are referring just that query with NOT EXISTS/EXISTS can be more efficient than normal query?

Comment: @GauravS . . . `NOT EXISTS` with a correlated subquery has fine performance.  What you refer to as "run for each statement" is simply an index lookup, which should be really, really fast.

Comment: @GordonLinoff:- Thanks for the details.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for your inputs, i am using this query as a part of spark sql which seems to be very network intensive and causing lot of  shuffle, could you suggest some alternative for this. I am not using indexes for the tables.

Comment: @SumitKhurana . . . This question is tagged MySQL.  If you have a question about SparkSQL, then ask another question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have edited my question with the correct tag